# Pandas update column based on current values

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to add some zeroes to zipcodes that came in numeric format. I thought this would work (it worked in previous similar situations with `.str.startswith()`. Any suggestions?

```
data['loczipstr'] = data['loczip'].astype(str)
data['loczipstr'] = np.where(len(data['loczipstr']) == 3, "0000" +data['loczipstr'], data['loczipstr'])
data['loczipstr'] = np.where(len(data['loczipstr']) == 4, "000" + data['loczipstr'], data['loczipstr'])
data['loczipstr'] = np.where(len(data['loczipstr']) == 5, "00" + data['loczipstr'], data['loczipstr'])
data['loczipstr'] = np.where(len(data['loczipstr']) == 6, "0" + data['loczipstr'], data['loczipstr'])
```

The lines execute but then do not change `data['loczipstr']` at all.

note: the lengths range from 3 to 6 because the four digit zipcodes look like `1023.0`, thus a char length of 6

Comment: Actually aren't you just `zfill`ing on 7 length strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the df to `str` and then use vectorised `str.zfill` on the `max` length of 7:

```
In [76]:
df['loczipstr'] = df['loczip'].astype(str).str.zfill(7)
df

Out[76]:
     loczip loczipstr
0       111   0000111
1     11111   0011111
2    111111   0111111
3   1111111   1111111
4  11111111  11111111
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and create `mask` with [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
print data
     loczip
0       111
1     11111
2    111111
3   1111111
4  11111111

data['loczipstr'] = data['loczip'].astype(str)

data.loc[data['loczipstr'].str.len() == 3, 'loczipstr'] = "0000" + data['loczipstr']
data.loc[data['loczipstr'].str.len() == 4, 'loczipstr'] = "000"  + data['loczipstr']
data.loc[data['loczipstr'].str.len() == 5, 'loczipstr'] = "00"   + data['loczipstr']
data.loc[data['loczipstr'].str.len() == 6, 'loczipstr'] = "0"    + data['loczipstr']
print data
     loczip loczipstr
0       111   0000111
1     11111   0011111
2    111111   0111111
3   1111111   1111111
4  11111111  11111111
```

Comment: thank you! will accept later. I don't use `loc` very often, I should probably look into that